# how to solve ViewDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, view

I'm new to Django 1.4 and try my first project. It's OK to create the app:

```
./manage.py startapp APP_NAME
```

and recognized by Django in urls.py as following:

```
(r'^home/$', 'APP_NAME.views.home'),
```

but when I only create a APP_NAME.py files in root directory of projects，and change the urls.py file as following:

```
(r'^home/$', 'APP_NAME.home'),
```

the debug page tell me ViewDoesNotExist. Even if I change the urls.py file to (with from...import and without single quotes):

```
from APP_NAME import home
(r'^home/$', home),
```

It also doesn't work.

How to solve it? It intricate to create APP for every view file.

Comment: it's best to follow the django convention laid out in the tutorial.  not doing so will lead to much pain.

Comment: do you mean create app is the correct way?

Comment: yes, startapp should give you an app "folder" containing a \_\_init\_\_.py file, and views.py file (if not create it here).  'APP_NAME.views.home' is looking for the "home" function in the views.py file, in the "APP_NAME" folder.

Comment: but how does this example take effect? It do write only single views.py file in the project. [http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html)

Comment: I just think if I create app for every view, then that would be many many empty models.py file in these app folders

Comment: you can create multiple functions within your views.py file. def display_x(), def edit_x(), etc.. within the app you created.

Comment: if you haven't done it the tutorial gives you a good intro https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually implemented your home function in 'APP_NAME.__init__.py'; if not, your code will not work, because there is nothing that can be called

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py startapp news
```

In your created `news` directory there is a `views.py`. Now lets add something:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

now in your `urls.py` you add this:

```
(r'^news/$', 'news.index'),
```

Just start the devserver `python manage.py runserver` and point your browser to `http://localhost:8000/news/`

You should see "Hello".

Now you could add in your `news/views.py` some more stuff - like `details`, `archive` and so on.

Also be sure to have an empty `__init__.py` file in every directory you'd like to import.
`from app.views import something` will not work if there's no init-file within the app-directory.